# Sending Json Objects to Laravel via Post

Tags: php, actionscript-3, http, laravel

I'm currently having some dificulty understanding how the framework works, as in sending data from as3. Currently I have this code on Laravel:

```
Route::get('HelloWorld',function(){return "Hello World";});
//Method returns a Hello World - works

Route::post('Register/{nome?}' ,'AccountController@Register');
//Method returns a string saying "How are you" - doesn't process
```

On AccountController:

```
public function Register($nome){
    return "How are you";
}
```

On my AS3, I'm currently doing this for these methods:

```
request.url = "http://myip/HelloWorld";
request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receiveLoginConfirmation);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, notAllowed);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, notFound);
loader.load(request);
//Works


var variables: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.nome = "Pedro";

request.url = "http://myip/Register";
request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")];
request.data = variables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receiveRegisterConfirmation);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, notAllowed);
loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, notFound); 
loader.load(request);
//Trying to understand the error, it gives me httperror 500, if I comment request.data it gives me httperror 405.
```

The doubt im having is understanding how to proceed to receive information in laravel AND determine if my as3 request is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to note the difference between the request body and the url parameters. In your route you are defining a 'nome' parameter, which is different than the request body, nome will always be a string. 
If you want to get data from that nome parameter your AS3 code should be like this:

```
request.url = "http://myip/Register/SomeNameLikePedro";
```

And if you want to send JSON from AS3 just keep that code but you have to modify some things in your Laravel code

```
// no need to set nome as a url parameter
Route::post('Register' ,'AccountController@Register');

public function Register($request) {
    $data = $request->all();
    // you can access nome variable like
    $nome = $data['nome'];
    $otherVariable = $data['otherVariable'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Damn, I completly forgot about this topic, I had such struggle back then XD thank you!